# Stream socket application on Android and PC

Tags: android, sockets

I need to build an application to send files from PC to Android smartphone. In the PC side, i am using C# program to read the file and send it through a stream socket, in Android side I must build a program to receive the file as a stream. So anyone can help me or give a simple step by step stream socket application.

Answer (score 0):

While ago I was using this to read stream sent via socket from IOS and Mac so I guess it should work for you too :

```
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        Socket client = null;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5000); // port number which the server will use to send the stream
            Log.d("","CREATE SERVER SOCKET");
        } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            if(serverSocket!=null){
                client = serverSocket.accept();
                client.setKeepAlive(true);
                client.setSoTimeout(10000);
                InputStream is = client.getInputStream();

                Log.w("READ","is Size : "+is.available());

                byte[] bytes = DNSUtils.readBytes(is);

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and this is how you actually read the sent bytes :

```
  public static byte[] readBytes(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
     // this dynamically extends to take the bytes you read
     ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

     // this is storage overwritten on each iteration with bytes
     int bufferSize = 1024;
     byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

     // we need to know how may bytes were read to write them to the byteBuffer
     int len = 0;
     while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
       byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
     }

     // and then we can return your byte array.
     return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
 }
```

Hope it will work for you too.